# Smack 3.2.2 SASL authentication DIGEST-MD5 failed: invalid-authzid

Tags: java, smack, sasl

I have big problem. Every time when I'm trying to connect to any jabber server I have got "SASL authentication DIGEST-MD5 failed" notification. I dont have this error when I dont use JPasswordField, but using JTextField in IM is pointless. I have tried every method I found, but it's all thesame.

The code:

```
private void bLoginAction(JTextField login, JPasswordField pass) {
loginText = login.getText();
passText = pass.getPassword().toString();
String[] data = loginText.split("@");
Connection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration(data[1], 5222);
Connection con = new XMPPConnection(config);
 try {
 con.connect();
 } catch (XMPPException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }
try {
 con.login(loginText, passText);
 } catch (XMPPException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 }  
}
```

Print from  printStackTrace():

> SASL authentication DIGEST-MD5 failed: invalid-authzid:  at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:
>   337)  at
>   org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.login(XMPPConnection.java:203) 
>   at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:348)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use *toString()*.  Try using *getPassword()* instead as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/passwordfield.html).  Even with a JTextField, you should be using *getText()* instead of *toString()*.

This is not a smack issue but a straight up Java one.

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly! I just have to build String from char[]. String passText = new String ( pass.getPassword()); if anybody need this;)